# Unable to generate *.deb file after running this sh script

Tags: linux, bash, deb

I am trying to build the source of [Cura](https://github.com/daid/Cura) for Linux Mint 64 Bit. The project has info on how to build as follows,

```
git clone https://github.com/daid/Cura.git

sudo apt-get install python-opengl python-numpy python-serial python-setuptools python-wxgtk2.8 curl arduino

cd Cura

./package.sh debian_amd64          # or debian_i386 for 32bit
# this will prompt for your root password to run dpkg-deb

sudo dpkg -i ./scripts/linux/cura*.deb
```

This is the build script.
[package.sh](https://github.com/daid/Cura/blob/SteamEngine/package.sh)

After executing `./package.sh debain_amd64` , a new **tar.gz** is created instead of .deb file. Why so?

I have tried unzipping and searched for INSTALL or README file but it contains the same description from the site.

Am I missing any additional packages related to Linux Mint ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Re: After executing ./package.sh **debain**_amd64 , a new tar.gz is
>   created instead of .deb file. Why so?

The problem is the typo in your argument is causing the script to build for darwin (OS X) and not debian. Fix the typo `debain`, so that it's `debian`:

```
./package.sh debian_amd64
```

Comment: In the script it appears to be `debian`

Comment: Correct, although the command used shows `debain`, resulting in the wrong package being built.

Comment: The op could have copy pasted it ;)

Comment: Regardless, `debain` along with poor error checking in the script is the likely culprit.

Comment: Thanks. It was my typo. Being new to shell script.  But I wish there was some error checking written in the script instead of building for all kinds of input.

Comment: @PraveenMax: I would recommend you [submit an issue report](https://github.com/daid/Cura/issues/new) regarding the lack of error checking to the developer; it can only help I think. Typos are a natural occurance, however, the script should consider that.